# Change stylesheet based on users timestamp on local machine. Javascript solution?

Tags: php, javascript, css, datetime

I have a project in mind where I would like to change the stylesheet based on time of day. I had initially done this with php, but it grabbed the server's time. Which was a less than ideal experience considering time zone differences.

I figure javascript may be the best bet to grab the users local time but I am not sure how I would write it. [This is similar to what I had in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241917/change-stylesheet-based-on-month-season-in-jquery), but I am thinking more every 3-6 hours change styles. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$stylesheets = array(
    'foo.css',
    'bar.css',
    'baz.css',
    // ...
    'qux.css'
);

$numStylesheets = count($stylesheets);

if (24 % $numStylesheets !== 0) {
    echo 'Number of stylesheets needs to be a factor of 24.';
    exit;
}

$hour = (int)date('H', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
$changeEveryXHours = 24 / $numStylesheets;
$offset = floor($hour / $changeEveryXHours);
$stylesheet = $stylesheets[$offset];

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="', $stylesheet, '" />';
```

It's dynamic, based on the number of stylesheets you specify.  Currently the number of stylesheets needs to be a factor of 24 (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24).  You could get rid of this requirement by modifying the code to use minutes and seconds instead of just hours, but that's too much math for me this morning. :-)

**Edit:** Here's the same script in JS:

```
var stylesheets = [
    'foo.css',
    'bar.css',
    'baz.css',
    // ...
    'qux.css'
];

if (24 % stylesheets.length != 0) {
    alert('Number of stylesheets needs to be a factor of 24.');
    return false;
}

var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
var changeEveryXHours = 24 / stylesheets.length;
var offset = Math.floor(hour / changeEveryXHours);
var stylesheet = stylesheets[offset];

// If you're using jQuery, I think it's something like this:
$('<link>')
    .prop({
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: stylesheet
    })
    .appendTo($('head'));
```

Comment: The factor of 24 actually will work well in this situation. But, I am not sure about the time stamp if it will grab the server or local, I will have to try this out. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Ah.. sorry about that, I guess I should have read your question more carefully.  Yes, to use the client's time, you'll have to use JS.  You could use AJAX to send the client's time to the server and have the server respond with the correct stylesheet to use (and then `document.write()` it or whatever).  Or you could replicate this script's logic in JS, which would be pretty straightforward - you'd just need to use `var now = new Date(); var hour = dt.getHours();` instead.

Answer (score 0):

From the guide at:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/

I reccommend you start reading from the section headlined "ALTERNATE"

using the `alternate` property together with the function:

Comment: Hey @Ernest Marcinko thanks for your answer, but it would be more desirable that you (at the very least) paste an excerpt from the page at the link that could answer this specific question. Thanks

FYI this answer's been marked as low quality, please read the guidelines for answering questions

Answer (score 0):

First of all you two options 
do it with jQuery (JavaScript) only 
OR jQuery & PHP

If you done it with PHP before you could send the current time using ajax request to PHP function and return the stylesheet needed then put it in the head

```
function do_it()
{
 now = new Date();
 current_time = now.getHours()+':'+now.getMinutes()+':'+now.getSeconds();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "your_php_script.php",
  data:{ current_user_time: current_time}
}).done(function( data ) {
//maybe you will need some logic here :) 
//and get the old file name 
  $('link[href^=old_css_file.css]').attr('href',data);
});
}

setInterval(function(){ 
do_it();
//cal it every 3 hours 
}, 10800000);
```

Comment: This gets fairly precise which may be ideal for what I am trying to do. I will have to try this out later and combine it with my php script. Thanks very much for the help!